# Changes in Vtiger CRM

Tags: javascript, php, crm, vtiger

I want to convert Vtiger CRM's Gregorian calendar to another calendar. As I see almost all calendars functions that are related to the user are in front-end, but I haven't in depth view. Is it necessary to change back-end codes (php) in addition to the front-end?